# Empty array element in Excel worksheet range showing ISBLANK = FALSE

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am writing an array to a range in a Column. The array consists of numbers and blanks.  When stored in the range, the numbers are displayed in scientific notation. To ensure that they are displayed as text, I have formatted the Column using the below code:

```
dws.Columns("m:m").NumberFormat = "@"
```

Now, the numbers are correctly displayed and although the blank cells have len = 0,  ISBLANK = FALSE. As a result, I am unable to use the COUNTIF function to count the cells with numbers.

(If the Numberformat = "@" code is removed then the COUNTIF works correctly except that the numbers are not displayed as required.)

Looking forward to some quick solution/workaround to the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "array element"? Do you place the range in an array? If not, what does that sintagme mean? If you transform the format in string, of course, everything is a string, which can be counted only with `CountA`, but for all of them, not only for numeric values. If you want both conditions (all strings and counting numbers) you should place them in an array and create a custom function iterating the array elements and checking as `IsNumeric(arr(i,1))`...  Otherwise, firstly count them and only after that set `NumberFormat = "@"`.

Answer (score 0):

As you have only blanks and/or values that can interpreted as numeric you might profit from just using the `COUNTA()` function which **omits** counting *blanks* despite prior `NumberFormat = "@" applied to the referenced (column) range:

- in cell: `=COUNTA(M:M)`
- via VBA: `WorksheetFunction.CountA(dws.Columns("M:M"))`

*Note: this assumes the columns reference `M:M` within a worksheet (i.e. not referring to a table for instance).*

Comment: @user1955215 Posted a simple solution to your counting issue; feel free to upvote and/or accept if helpful.